# Convergence of product of a convergent series and a non negative bounded sequence

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

To begin, this is a HW problem so I would only like a hint and not the whole solution. The problem is as following: 
We have a nonegative convergent infinite sum $\sum a_n$ and $b_n$ be a non negative, bounded sequence. Show that $\sum a_n \cdot b_n$ converges.
My current idea is to use something like a comparison test and show that $b_n * a_n \le a_n$ but that doesn't work if $b_n$ is bounded in $(0,1)$ so right now I'm stuck and have no idea how to approach this.

Comment: What does "nonnegative convergent infinite sum" mean? That all $a_n \ge 0$ or that $\sum a_n \ge 0$?

Comment: I think that the author of the book meant that it has nonnegative terms. So both I guess?

Comment: Then all $a_n \ge 0$ and everything is okay.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter the bound for $(b_{n})$. For $0\leq b_{n}\leq M$, we have $s_{n}:=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}b_{k}$, then $s_{n}\leq M\displaystyle\sum a_{n}$, so $(s_{n})$ is a bounded increasing sequence, and hence convergent.

Comment: Okay this kind of confuses me so sorry if my question is stupid. So we have $s_n$ as a sequence of sums, right? And from there we get the inequality how exactly? I don't quite understand that step. I would appreciate if you could explain that, but your solution actually gave me an idea idea on how to do it so thanks either way.

Comment: Yes, in particular, it is still a sequence, so we are looking at the convergence of $(s_{n})$.

Comment: Let's see if OP means that or not.